# Сделать некоторые ссылки в меню под вопросами - кнопками

Tags: дефект, дизайн, доступность

У нас есть меню под вопросами:

[image: скриншот меню]

скринридером (программой для чтения страницы голосом) это меню читается вот таким образом:

> мод  кнопка
>
> поделиться  ссылка    короткая постоянная ссылка на этот вопрос
>
> править  ссылка    отредактируйте сообщение, чтобы улучшить его
>
> отслеживать  кнопка    Нажмите «отслеживать», чтобы получать уведомления.
>
> закрыть  ссылка    голосовать за закрытие вопроса (если вопрос закрыт, на него нельзя дать ответ)
>
> удалить  ссылка    голосовать за удаление этого сообщения
>
> тревога  ссылка    отметьте тревогой сообщение с целью обозначить серьёзную проблему или привлечь внимание модератора

Мне кажется, что всё кроме <kbd>поделиться</kbd> и <kbd>править</kbd> стоит сделать кнопками.

Comment: Зачем? Что ещё за "скринридер"? И почему это на ruSO.meta?

Comment: Скриншот приложите, плиз.

Comment: @Kromster, скриншот чего?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, NVDA, но в данном случае без разницы. А почему бы не тут?

Comment: Вы нам тут какой-то дамп скинули, непонятный. Скриншот бы помог разобраться что у вас там не так.

Comment: Скриншот скринридера - рукалицо...

Comment: @Kromster, раз уж так хочется, я добавил абсолютно бесполезный скриншот меню, которое и так есть под каждым сообщением.

Comment: То есть вы пользуетеь софтом, который вам читает страничку вслух. Ок. И в чем конкретно ваше неудобство, чем вам поможет замена ссылок на кнопки?

Comment: @Kromster, читаются вперемешку ссылки и кнопки. Логически всё кроме "поделиться" и "править" - кнопки, поскольку как ссылки они никуда не ведут. А ещё кнопки можно нажимать пробелом. Кстати, там ещё в браузерном меню есть "открыть в новой вкладке", которое открывает само сообщение и не имеет ни малейшего отношение к действию кнопки.

Comment: Под вопросом кнопка "править", воспользуйтесь ей чтобы уточнить вопрос.